# Creating bundles with Multiple instances of the same product in them

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, configuration, bundled-product

I'm a bit on the new side to Magento (currently using version 1.9) and I'd like to offer various bundles of the products I'm offering as options on the product page.

Essentially the pricing is as follows: A "Sample Pack" of a product will be $0.99 (and 1 include of the product)

A Standard pack will be $2.99 (and include 4 of the product)

A double pack will be $ 4.99 (and include 8 of the product)

I'd like these to appear as options on the product page and when ordered remove the correct number of items from my inventory (e.g. ordering a sample pack will remove 1 of the products from the inventory, ordering 2 double packs will remove 16 etc)

I've tried various methods using custom options and bundles but I can't find a way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to achieve some measure of success with this using the "Simple Bundles" feature within the product.

Creating several simple bundles containing only various quantities of the product in question creates an effect similar to what I was trying to achieve